# How do i make listbox items not selectable?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

In WPF, is there a way to make a listbox not selectable using Styles etc.? If not, is it possible to set a style that prevents the selected item from changing its background and border?

Comment: I believe you can achieve that with IsEnabled property

Comment: If you want all the items to be non selectable, there's a discussion on that here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1722456/make-listbox-items-in-wpf-not-selectable