# How to prevent accidental xaml control "selection"

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, selection

I've noticed a strange bug when creating a desing with xaml:

sometimes I'm able to "select" controls the way I'd select text.

Normally the controls would look like this:

[image]

while if accidental selection happens, it looks like this:

[image]

Why does this happen, and how do I prevent it?

**UPDATE**

Here's the controls that I'm using:
TreeView->Expander->StackPanel->DataGrid

Based on the answers, the problem probably originates from TreeView.

How do I prevent TreeView items from being selected?

Comment: I'm guessing your using a ListBox that has a SelectedItem rather than an ItemsControl? If you don't need a SelectedItem use an ItemsControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears your control is based off a listbox which supports being able to select items in that manner.  Perhaps change the underlying control to be based on an 'items control' instead.

Edit:

Tree view has the same behavior allowing to select an item.  See this question...

[Disable WPF TreeView (or TreeViewItem) selection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4554298/disable-wpf-treeview-or-treeviewitem-selection)

Answer (score 2):

That should only be the case if the control is inside something selectable like a `ListBoxItem`, to prevent that use [`ItemsControls`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) instead of subclasses of [`Selector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.aspx) (e.g. `ListBox`). If that is not it i don't know what is going on as i have never seen something like that.

---

Judging from your edit you appear to have `TreeViewItems`, you could [either override the respective brush-keys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1398625/546730) to hide the selection or add a `TreeView.ItemContainerStyle` which changes the `Template` to something which will not show the selection in the first place.