# ListView, Select Item before ContextFlyout opens or Item is dragged

Tags: uwp

I have a ListView with a context menu, and that can be reordered.
I would like it to behave very much like the thumbnails in a power-point presentation (and many other applications):

- If you right-click on a page that is not selected yet, then it becomes the selected page before the context menu pops-up
- If you start dragging a page that is not selected yet, then it becomes the selected page before dragging.

Xaml :

```
<Page
    x:Class="TestApp.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TestApp"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Page.Resources>
        <MenuFlyout x:Key="EditFlyout">
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Copy" Icon="Copy"/>
            <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Paste" Icon="Paste"/>
        </MenuFlyout>
    </Page.Resources>
    
    <Grid>
        <ListView
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Pages, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectionMode="Extended"
            CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True"
            ContextFlyout="{StaticResource EditFlyout}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:DocPage">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Code:

```
namespace TestApp
{
        public class DocPage
        {
            public string Name;
            // Edit: actual class is more complex and includes rendered bitmap thumbnail etc...
        }
    
        public sealed partial class MainPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
        {
            public ObservableCollection<DocPage> Pages = new ObservableCollection<DocPage>();
    
            public MainPage()
            {
                this.InitializeComponent();
                DocPage PageA = new DocPage() { Name = "PageA" };
                DocPage PageB = new DocPage() { Name = "PageB" };
                Pages.Add(PageA);
                Pages.Add(PageB); // duplicates are intended, we cannot differentiale a selection by "item"
                Pages.Add(PageB);
                Pages.Add(PageA); 
                Pages.Add(PageB);
                Pages.Add(PageB);
            }
        }
    }
```

How can I achieve this?

Edit : One way to meet the expected behavior would be that the ListView logic of selection / multi-selection (with ctrl / shift) be triggered when the item is pressed rather than when it is released. Apparently on WPF the selection logic happens when an item is pressed, but in UWP this happens when the item is released, not sure why ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589142/why-does-the-wpf-listbox-change-selection-on-mouse-button-down-rather-than-butto))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If you right-click on a page that is not selected yet, then it becomes the selected page before the context menu pops-up

For this scenario, you could listen ListView `RightTapped` event, and it will execute when the  menu pops-up, you could get current clicked item and pass it to ListView's Selecteditem

```
private void MyListView_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
        ListView listView = (ListView)sender;



        DocPage targetItem = ((FrameworkElement)e.OriginalSource).DataContext as DocPage;



        var index = Pages.IndexOf(targetItem);
        if (index >= 1 && index < Pages.Count)
        {
            MyListView.SelectedIndex = index;
        }
       
 }
```

> If you start dragging a page that is not selected yet, then it becomes the selected page before dragging.

When you drag listview item, it will invoke `DragItemsStarting` event, for this scenario, please get the drag item and make it as selected state.

```
private void ListView_DragItemsStarting(object sender, DragItemsStartingEventArgs e)
{
    // The ListView is declared with selection mode set to Single.
    // But we want the code to be robust
    if (e.Items.Count == 1)
    {
        DocPage targetItem = e.Items[0] as DocPage;



        var index = Pages.IndexOf(targetItem);



        if (index >= 1 && index < Pages.Count)
        {
            MyListView.SelectedIndex = index;
        }



    }
}
```

> duplicates are intended, we cannot differentiale a selection by "item"

We suggest you use the class instance with specific it  to replace normal value as listview item.

**Xaml code**

```
 <ListView
            x:Name="MyListView"
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind Pages, Mode=OneWay}"
            SelectionMode="Extended"
            CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True"
            RightTapped="MyListView_RightTapped"
            CanDragItems="True"
            DragItemsStarting="ListView_DragItemsStarting"
            ContextFlyout="{StaticResource EditFlyout}">
           
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:DocPage">
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks Nico. I guess you ment index >= 0 and should remove the "// The ListView is declared with selection mode set to Single."  in the answer.

Comment: Here are the issues I see in the solution proposed : For the "duplicates are intended, we cannot differentiale a selection by item", I don't understand your answer. The actual class is more complex than in the sample so I did not want to duplicate the instance, and the IndexOf solution does not work. For the solution, I would very much prefer the selection to be triggered at first  tap rather than when the dragging starts. I was wondering if all 3  could be solved by listening some Itemcontainer event.

Comment: I mean, you need to make class instance with specific id, and query it with id.