# Windows phone 8 How to add border to item in itemscontrol

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone

I'm new to Windows Phone and I have stuck in this for days.

What I need is a list with border on each items.

First I try to use `ListBox`,which easy to add border to item by using `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`,but I found items in `ListBox` will change color while tab on it,so I searching for prevent,at last I found all available solutions in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398559/there-is-no-listbox-selectionmode-none-is-there-another-way-to-disable-select/1398625#1398625),but the accept answer is not working on Windows Phone, and some answers says make `ListBox` disabled will be work.So I set `IsHitTestVisible` to false, but it will cause all buttons in item disabled.

So I came back to `ItemsControl` at last,it has no `ItemContainerStyle` property in Windows Phone but every result I googled says that.I tried set border in template but it didn't work at all.

This issue is driving me crazy,any suggestions please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not define an ItemTemplate? You can exactly specify how each item should look. For example:

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
   <DataTemplate>
      <Border>
       <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="18" TextWrapping="Wrap" 
             Margin="3 1" /> 
       </Border>                
    </DataTemplate>
 </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: Wow!Just so simple takes me so long!I have tried add border style to Grid which in template but it did't work.Anyway,this works perfect,thank you very much.